# Changing structure of simple table

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table like this:

```
Area     AgeGroup     RateOfSales
London     0-18             100
London     19-64            200
London     65+              300
York       0-18             50
York       19-64            150
York       65+              250

Area       0-18    19-64     65+
London      100     200      300
York        50      150      250
```

I.e. pivot so each AgeGroup variable is a column.

Can anyone advise please, I am new to R and just getting to grips with the dplyr function.

Thank you!

Comment: Regarding the table: please **don’t** try to post pictures. Posting the table as text (or a formatted table …) is not only encouraged but *required*. Pictures are useless.

Comment: FYI, terminology: `dplyr` is an R *package*, not a function; it contains many functions within it, that are made available when you `library(dplyr)`. However, pivoting data is something better handled by other packages, such as `tidyr` (a close cousin of `dplyr`, using `tidyr::pivot_*` functions), `data.table`, and `reshape2`.